# Login Page C# (Inconsistency)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, passwords

I am doing a login page that makes use of controller and login form. When i enter a invalid username i am not able to login. But when i just enter my username and a wrong password.. i am allowed to login. What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: There are *so* many things wrong here, I don't know where to start. The most obvious, first, one, is that (from what I can see) you check whether the username exists and whether the password exists, but never bother to check whether those two events correspond to the same user (let along that multiple users may have the same password, and it just selects the first user with a given password). Other issues: searching in code rather than SQL, Unsalted password hashes, stringly-typed code,... (I'm sure there are more if I keep looking)

Comment: I'm so confused about ur code. You create and call so many methods to do a simple job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ur method can be simply like this

Login method

```
public bool Login(string username, string password)
{
   User[] userList = GetAllUsers();
   for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (user[i].GetUsername() == username && user[i].GetPassword == password)
            {
              return true;                
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Login Button Click

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = this.LoginUsernameTextBox.Text;
        string passwd = this.LoginPasswordTextBox.Text;       


        if (Login(userName, passwd))
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Unsuccessfully!");
        }   
    }
```

But i suggest u not to get all users out of database. You have to create method to search user by Query

Comment: Do NOT take all users out of the database. That is just wrong. Also, I completely relate to Damien's comment to the question.

Comment: I just follow his coding way :) ACtually, he must create Method Query Select from Database :)

Comment: What should be the correct structure of my code given that taking out all users from the database is a bad practice? Can anyone tell me how can i make adjustment to my codes to make it shorten yet doing the same function?